# Displaying data from SQLite table's columns, one of which holds an array

Tags: json, android-sqlite

I managed to retrieve the SQLite table with only the first item of the array and put it in the UI's TextView. Couldn't get all the of the array's items. From each of the rest of the columns, a single value is returned successfully.

The JSON is parsed and passed as a parcelable ArrayList to a Fragment where it's presented in a list. Clicking on a list item directs to another Fragment where all the of item's details are presented.

I've been trying to write a for loop that returns the Strings in the array into the TextView, but the condition `i < genresList.size()` is always false. I tried using a while loop, but it returns only the first item of the list.
Various ways I've found on the internet didn't work.

Thanks.

**Parsing and insertion to SQLite**

```
private void parseJsonAndInsertToSQLIte(SQLiteDatabase db) throws JSONException {
        // parsing the json
        String jsonString = getJsonFileData();
        JSONArray moviesArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
        ContentValues insertValues;

        for (int i = 0; i < moviesArray.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject jsonObject = moviesArray.getJSONObject(i);

            String title = jsonObject.getString("title");
            String imageUrl = jsonObject.getString("image");
            String rating = jsonObject.getString("rating");
            String releaseYear = jsonObject.getString("releaseYear");

            JSONArray genresArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("genre");
            List<String> genres = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int k = 0; k < genresArray.length(); k++) {
                genres.add(genresArray.getString(k));
            }

            insertValues = new ContentValues();

            insertValues.put(Movie.TITLE, title);
            insertValues.put(Movie.IMAGE_URL, imageUrl);
            insertValues.put(Movie.RATING, rating);
            insertValues.put(Movie.RELEASE_YEAR, releaseYear);
            for (int k = 0; k < genresArray.length(); k++) {
                insertValues.put(Movie.GENRE, genres.get(k));
            }
            Log.i(TAG, "insertValues: " + genresArray);

            long res = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, insertValues);

            Log.i(TAG, "parsed and inserted to sql - row: " + res);
        }
    }
```

**The item's details Fragment**

```
public class MovieDetailsFragment extends Fragment{

... variables declarations come here...

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NotNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_details_movie, container, false);

        Context context = getActivity();

        Bundle idBundle = getArguments();
        if (idBundle != null) {
            movieId = getArguments().getInt("id");
        }

        getDatabase = new GetDatabase(context);
        getDatabase.open();
        Cursor cursor = getDatabase.getMovieDetails(movieId);

... more irelevant code comes here...

        titleView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.movieTtlId);
        ratingView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.ratingId);
        releaseYearView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.releaseYearId);
        genreView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.genreID);

        String titleFromSQLite = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Movie.TITLE));
        String ratingFromSQLite = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Movie.RATING));
        String releaseYearFromSQLite = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Movie.RELEASE_YEAR));

        String genreFromSQLite;
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                genreFromSQLite = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Movie.GENRE));
                genres.add(genreFromSQLite);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        else{
            genreFromSQLite = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Movie.RELEASE_YEAR));
        }
        getDatabase.close();

//more irelevant code comes here

        genreView.setText(genreFromSQLite);
        genreView.setFocusable(false);
        genreView.setClickable(false);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

**The method that returns the table from SQLite:**

```
    public ArrayList<Movie> getMovies() {
        String[] columns = {
                Movie.ID,
                Movie.TITLE,
                Movie.IMAGE_URL,
                Movie.RATING,
                Movie.RELEASE_YEAR,
                Movie.GENRE
        };

        // sorting orders
        String sortOrder =
                Movie.RELEASE_YEAR + " ASC";
        ArrayList<Movie> moviesList = new ArrayList<>();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, //Table to query
                columns,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                sortOrder);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Movie movie = new Movie();
                movie.setMovieId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Movie.ID))));
                movie.setTitle(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Movie.TITLE)));
                movie.setImageUrl(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Movie.IMAGE_URL)));
                movie.setRating(cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(Movie.RATING)));
                movie.setReleaseYear(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Movie.RELEASE_YEAR)));

                List<String> genreArray = new ArrayList<>();
                while(cursor.moveToNext()){
                    String genre = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Movie.GENRE));
                    genreArray.add(genre);
                }

                movie.setGenre(Collections.singletonList(String.valueOf(genreArray)));

                // Adding a movie to the list
                moviesList.add(movie);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "The movies list from sqlite: " + moviesList);
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        return moviesList;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your issue is with :-

```
        for (int k = 0; k < genresArray.length(); k++) {
            insertValues.put(Movie.GENRE, genres.get(k));
        }
```

That will result in just the last value in the loop being inserted as the key/column name (first parameter of the put) does not change (and probably can't as you only have the one column).

You could use :-

```
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int k = 0; k < genresArray.length(); k++) {
            if (k > 0) {
                sb.append(",");
            }
            sb.append(genres.get(k));
        }
        insertValues.put(Movie.GENRE, sb.toString());
```

- Note the above code is in-principle code. It has not been tested or run and may therefore contains errors.

This would insert all the data as a CSV into the GENRE column.

**BUT** that is not a very good way as far as utilising databases. It would be far better if the Genre's were a separate table and probably that a mapping table were used (but that should be another question).

This is going to cause you issues as well :-

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Movie movie = new Movie();
                movie.setMovieId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Movie.ID))));
                movie.setTitle(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Movie.TITLE)));
                movie.setImageUrl(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Movie.IMAGE_URL)));
                movie.setRating(cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(Movie.RATING)));
                movie.setReleaseYear(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Movie.RELEASE_YEAR)));

                List<String> genreArray = new ArrayList<>();
                while(cursor.moveToNext()){
                    String genre = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Movie.GENRE));
                    genreArray.add(genre);
                }

                movie.setGenre(Collections.singletonList(String.valueOf(genreArray)));

                // Adding a movie to the list
                moviesList.add(movie);

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
```

That is you move to the first row of the Cursor, extract some data MoveieId,Title ... ReleaseYear.

Then

a) if there any other rows you move to the next (which would be for a different Movie) and the next until you finally reached the last row adding elements to the genreArray.

or

b) If there is only the one row in the Cursor genreArray is empty.

You then add the 1 and only movie to the movieList and return.

1 move (row) in the Cursor will exist per movie and there is only the 1 GENRE column per movie. You have to extract the data in that column and then **split** the data into the genreArray without moving (see the previous fix that will create a CSV (note that would be messed up if the data contained commas)).

**IF** you used the previous fix and store the multiple genres as a CSV, then you could use :-

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Movie movie = new Movie();
                movie.setMovieId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Movie.ID))));
                movie.setTitle(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Movie.TITLE)));
                movie.setImageUrl(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Movie.IMAGE_URL)));
                movie.setRating(cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(Movie.RATING)));
                movie.setReleaseYear(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Movie.RELEASE_YEAR)));
                List<String> genreArray = new List<>(Arrays.asList((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Movie.GENRE))).split(",",0)));

                movie.setGenre(Collections.singletonList(String.valueOf(genreArray)));

                // Adding a movie to the list
                moviesList.add(movie);

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
```

- Note the above code is in-principle code. It has not been tested or run and may therefore contains errors.

Comment: Hey Mike. Thank you for your answer. I created a method that gets called with the cursor as a parameter: `private List<String> getGenreArray(Cursor cursor) {
        return new List<String>(Arrays.asList((cursor.getString...` (it must implement about 45 overriding methods). I get the following error message: `List( ) 
in List cannot be applied
to
(java.util.List<java.lang.String>)
 `.

Comment: Regarding what you wrote about mapping table: a mapping table is using a table witin a table, right? What you mean by that is that I'll create a table with movies names and their respective genres?

Comment: @D.Joe Nope, you have a Movies table and Genres table and then to allow many-many relationships (A Movie can have many Genres and a Genre can be used by many Movies) a third table the mapping table has two columns (perhaps others) one references the Movie the other the Genre. Say you have 2 Movies id's 1 and 2 and 3 Genres 1 2 and 3. Then in the mapping table **2,3** would be Movie 2 has Genre 3; **1,2** would be Movie 1 has Genre 2; **1,3** Movie 1 has Genre 3 (so Movie 1 has many Genres additionally Genre 3 has many Movies) and so on.

Comment: @D.Joe re code. Something like `private List<String> getGenreArray(Cursor cursor) {
        return Arrays.asList((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Movie.GENRE))).split(",",0));
    }`

Comment: Thanks Mike. The genres list is finally showing properly.